# Error: EMBED_FIELD_VALUE (Discord.json bot)

Tags: javascript, json

**Script**:  -------------->

```
client.on('messageDelete', message =>{ 
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Message has been deleted!')
    .setColor('Red')
    .addField(`Deleted message:`, message.content, true)
    .addField("X-virus:",`${message.author.tag} (${message.author})`,true)
    .addField("Channel:", `${message.channel}`, false)
    .setFooter(' - ',`${message.author.avatarURL()}`)
    .setTimestamp(message.createdAt);
  client.channels.cache.get("850010512053370930").send(embed);
```

**Write Terminal**-------->

```
if (!value) throw new RangeError('EMBED_FIELD_VALUE');
                ^
RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.
    at Function.normalizeField (C:\Users\User\Desktop\discordbot-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:432:23)
    at C:\Users\User\Desktop\discordbot-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:452:14
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.normalizeFields (C:\Users\User\Desktop\discordbot-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:451:8)
    at MessageEmbed.addFields (C:\Users\User\Desktop\discordbot-master\node_modules\discord.js\sr    at MessageEmbed.addField (C:\Users\User\Desktop\discordbot-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:257:17)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\discordbot-master\main.js:40:6)
    at Client.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at MessageDeleteAction.handle (C:\Users\User\Desktop\discordbot-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageDelete.js:21:16)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_DELETE] (C:\Users\User\Desktop\discordbot-master\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_DELETE.js:4:32) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'EMBED_FIELD_VALUE'
```

This error: Problem in empty code or message delete